# Searching for literal "> \" using ack-grep

Tags: grep, regex, escaping

I am looking for lines that literally have a greater than character (a ">") followed by a space followed by a backslash character (a "\") 
  i.e., a line with this: > \

I thought escaping would allow this, and for the greater-than it does:

```
  $ ack-grep "\> "
```

returns lines that have "> " in them.

But when I try to escape the backslash as well I get:

```
  $ ack-grep "\> \\"
```

ack-grep: Invalid regex '\> \':
  Trailing \ in regex m/\> /

Answer (score 6):

Wow, I was so close ...  single quotes:

```
$ ack-grep '\> \\'
```

Figured this out after confirming that my regex match was valid using:
  http://regexpal.com/
and just happened to have had single quotes from trying something else.

Answer (score 5):

This also works:

```
$ ack-grep '> \\'
```

and so does:

```
$ ack-grep "> \\\\"
```

The greater-than doesn't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

To search literal strings, use the literal option:

```
ack-grep --literal '> \'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the issue here is not with ack but with the shell quoting.  You'd have this problem with any program that you were trying to pass in "> \" as an argument.

Comment: Yup, had I known this first: 
  http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~uwe/lehre/unixffb/quoting-guide.html

3.1.11 The golden rules of Bourne shell quoting
Everything else that might be maltreated by the shell is protected by single quotes.